# Why is the value of the "name" (check html code ln.40) not showing when i run the code?

Tags: python, html, forms, post, get

i'm learning python and just doing some practical exercises as a beginner. So, here i just want to show the entered player name down this short paragraph " current Team " (check html code ln. 40 down).
I know the problem is not more than a lack of experience from me, but I actually like doing exercices more than just theoretical learning :)

Here is the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])


def home():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    #app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 

    name = request.form.get('name')
     if len(name) < 1:
        flash('name is too short', category='error')
    else:
        def add_player():
            player = name
            print(name)
        add_player()   
        
        flash('player added', category="success")


 return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the html code(don't care about the style):

```
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymus"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymus"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css" />
    
    <title>Team Players</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div calss="firsdiv">
      <h1>Add Team Players</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" ></input>
        <br />
        <div align="relative">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show Down</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="center">
        <p>Current Team</p>
    
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="players">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              {{ player }}
             <!-- Here i want to show the entered players names down "current Team" when i run the code -->

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your python code with this: -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    #app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 

    name = request.form.get('name')
    if len(name) < 1:
        flash('name is too short', category='error')
    else:
        flash('player added', category="success")
        return render_template("index.html", player=name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

If you want to return all the players in current team, then you need to store it somewhere, that's why I have created a file called names.txt which will store all the players entered by the user in the current session, that means if the user closes or refreshes the website, then the names.txt file will get deleted meaning names will disappear. I guess this is what you have asked for.

python code: -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    os.remove('names.txt')
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    #app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 

    name = request.form.get('name')
    if len(name) < 1:
        flash('name is too short', category='error')
    else:
        flash('player added', category="success")
        file1 = open("names.txt",'a')
        file1.write(name+"\n")
        file1.close()

        file2 = open("names.txt", 'r')
        l = file2.readlines()
        file2.close()
        s = ','.join(l)
        return render_template("index.html", player=s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```